# Mysterious Spacing in text of SQL

Tags: sql, text, replace, spaces

I am trying to replace space in the notes(text) of my SQL.

```
select REPLACE(cast(notes as varchar(8000)), ' ', '.') 
as notes from nTable 
where CaseID = '1449686'
```

Result:

```
****  Topic:.Pre-sales.support  I.second.the.motion!
```

why isn't all the spaces getting replaced? (if I put in double spaces in the replace- nothing gets replaced).. what else could it be?

Comment: are you sure they are spaces and not tabulations?

Comment: Could be possible that those spaces are non-breaking spaces?

Comment: That was it- I changed my replace to look for char(13) - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Is the CaseID a varchar type?  Try it without single quotes:

```
select REPLACE(cast(notes as varchar(8000)), ' ', '.') 
as notes from nTable 
where CaseID = 1449686
```

Comment: maybe you don't understand my question? I want to replace the spaces, but it's not working. I imagine there is something there other than spaces... but I can't figure out what.

Comment: You might not be selecting the record at all if the datatype of CaseID is INT and you are querying a VARCHAR with single quotes, you will never select the record to REPLACE the characters.

Comment: If it didn't select the record, how could he have gotten a result?